# Range input to function in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

In a cell in my google sheet, I call my function like this: `myFunction(A1:A3)`, where A1 = 5, A2 = 7 and A3 = 3. I now want to loop over the input (A1, A2, and A3) and (for example) sum them.

```
function myFunction(input) {

if (!input.map) {     
return -1; 
}

var sum=0
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  sum = sum + parseInt(input[i]);
}

return sum

}
```

But it only returns the value in A1 (5) because `input.length` returns 1.
If I remove `parseInt(input[i])`, it returns "05,7,3"
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me...is there a reason to use the custom function over `=SUM(A1:A3)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom function arguments are converted to JavaScript object types. If the parameter is a multicell range, it's converted to an array object which members are arrays, in other words, as a 2D array.

In order to get each cell value, instead of `input[i]` use something like `input[i][j]`.

Example:

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function mySum(input) {
  if (!input.map) return -1; 
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < input[0].length; j++){
      sum = sum + parseInt(input[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return sum
}
```

Note: The above function could be improved by adding some rules / input data validation, like replace blanks by 0.

References

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Answer (score 1):

there's built functions for do that but if you want to learn how to script and code this is great !
the code works for just vertical ranges e.g (A1:A5) but in horizontal/square ranges wont, just do another loop inside the first one to do sum of 2D array

```
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<input[0].length; j++){
      sum = sum + parseInt(input[i][j]);
  }
}
```